# If $f(x)=2x^2-3x+4=0$ then what is $f(x+h)-f(x)/h$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What I would do is decide that $$g(x)=x+h$$ and then perform f composition g
$$f(g(x))=2(x+h)^2-3(x+h)+4$$ which equals $$f(g(x))=2x^2+4xh+2h^2-3x-3h+4$$ I would then input this equation into the difference quotient to get $$(2x^2+4xh+2h^2-3x-3h+4-(2x^2-3x+4))/h$$ After simplifying I get $$4x+2h-3$$
My Book says the answer is $$4x-2h+3$$ I am using CliffsNotes Algebra 2 Practice Pack and I haven proven it wrong before so I am wondering if it is me or the book.
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to define a new function g, and it's not necessary to do this, then I think you want $g(x)=x+h$.  Your answer is correct, though.

Comment: Instead of defining $f:R\to R$ as $f(x)=2x^2-3x+4$, try using a different variable (e.g. $f(t)=2t^2-3t+4$). That way you can easily substitute $x$ and $x+h$ in turn for $t$. Personally, I find  it less confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{array}{llr}
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}&=\frac{2(x+h)^2-3(x+h)+4 - 2x^2+3x-4}{h}\\
&=\frac{\color{blue}{2x^2}+4xh+2h^2\color{red}{-3x}-3h\color{green}{+4}\color{blue}{-2x^2}\color{red}{+3x}\color{green}{-4}}{h}\\
&=\frac{4xh-3h+2h^2}{h}\\
&=4x-3+2h\\
\end{array}$

---

The common goal of performing this operation is when being introduced to the concept of derivatives in which case we will take the limit of the result as $h$ approaches zero.  As others have pointed out, your question did not in fact specify that we would take limits.

Comment: There is no limit in the question.

Comment: @WillO and @ Pm2Ring Noted.